# RPC over HTTP on Exchange 2003 - Server Unavailable Error

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, rpc

OK, I've been working on this for two days, there's a ton of documentation and I've read everything I can find however I cannot get past this problem.

I want to migrate off this 2003 server to Office365 but I need to enable RPC over HTTP to migrate, so hopefully this will be my last issue with this server.

Using the Remote Connectivity Analyzer, I get through 7 tests and the 8th fails.  Not sure how many tests it runs, hoping this is the last.  The test that fails is:
Attempting to ping RPC endpoint 6001 (Exchange Information Store) on server mail.domain.com.

The Detailed error is:
The RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE error (0x6ba) was thrown by the RPC Runtime process.

That error links to this doc:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db543644-c252-47ee-a70b-4f60770083dc.aspx

Now I did most the troubleshooting suggestions.
The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Rpc\Rpcproxy key looks correct has the NetBIOS and the FQDN both in there for all three ports.
I can telnet to all three ports with no issues. 
The Event Viewer show no errors related to RPC or RPC Proxy.

So that leaves the generic DNS issues.  Now I'm not an DNS expert but from what I have tried DNS seems to be working.  What can I test or are there other area where I can look to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the configuration of the server. Is this a FE/BE Exchange setup or is this a single Exchange server? Do you have the RPC Proxy component installed?

Comment: Sorry. This is a single Exchange server, yes the RPC Proxy component is installed.

Comment: Download the Deployment Scenarios guide and make sure your server is configured accordingly, based on your scenario - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998950(v=exchg.65).aspx